# jQuery AJAX POST with result on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I cannot figure out AJAX.

How can I display checked results on index.php, clicked on link (AJAX - javascript function) to display those results on results.php page?

database.sql

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compare` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `shape` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `compare` (`id`, `company`, `image`, `size`, `price`, `color`, `shape`, `weight`) VALUES
(1, 'Adidas', '1.jpg', '7', 600, 'Blue', 'Normal', '50 gram'),
(2, 'Adidas', '2.jpg', '7', 700, 'Red Blue', 'Sports', '60 gram'),
(3, 'Nike', '3.jpg', '8', 800, 'Red Blue', 'Sports', '60 gram'),
(4, 'Puma', '4.jpg', '8', 1800, 'Red Black', 'Normal Sports', '70 gram'),
(5, 'Reebok', '5.jpg', '9', 2000, 'White Black', 'Normal Sports', 'N/A');
```

database.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass'); 
if (!$connect) { 
die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db('compare_test',$connect);
?>
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function compare()
{
var total_check = new Array();
$('.products:checked').each(function () {
    total_check.push($(this).val());
});

if (total_check != '') {
    if (total_check.length == '2') {
    var i = 0;
    var pidArray = new Object();
    $('.products:checked').each(function () {
    total_check.push($(this).val());
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    pidArray[i] = {
        pid: id
    };
    i++;
});
var data = JSON.stringify(pidArray);
var href = this.href;
//e.preventDefault();
$('#wait').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "compare.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {pids:data,type:'compare'},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            $('#wait').hide();
                document.location = "http://localhost/usp/results.php";
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please select two products ");
        return false;
    }
} else {
    alert("Please select minimum two products");
    return false;
}
}
 </script>

<tr>
    <td width="10%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="compare();" style="color:green;font-size:15px;"><b>Compare</b></a></td>
    <td width="20%">Product Image</td>
    <td width="20%">Comany Name</td>
    <td width="20%">Price</td>
    <td width="20%">Details</td>
</tr>
<?php $sql =mysql_query("Select * FROM compare");
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="products[]" class="products" id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><img src="image/<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" width="80" height="80px;"></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['company']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['price']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="detail" id="detail-<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Details</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

compare.php

```
<?php
    include('database.php');
    $Totalpids = (array)json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['pids']));
    foreach($Totalpids as $product)
    {
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM compare where id=".$product->pid."");
       $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
       $res .="<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='0' align='left' width='240'>
       <tr><th align='left'><strong>Product Details</strong></th></tr>
       <tr height='75' align='center'><td align='left'><img src='image/".$data['image']."' width='75px' height='75px'></td></tr>
       <tr height='40' align='center'><td align='left'>".$data['company']."</td></tr>
       <tr height='40' align='center'><td align='left'>".$data['size']."</td></tr>
       <tr height='40' align='center'><td align='left'>".$data['price']."</td></tr>
       <tr height='40' align='center'><td align='left'>".$data['color']."</td></tr>
       <tr height='40' align='center'><td align='left'>".$data['shape']."</td></tr>
       <tr height='40' align='center'><td align='left'>".$data['weight']."</td></tr>";
       $res .= "</table>";
       }
       echo $res;
       ?>
```

results.php

```
<?php
  // what here to display taht results?

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="hr">
<head>
<title>asd</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
(function($){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "compare.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.totalProducts = data || 0;
    }
    });
}(jQuery));
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Provide any suggestion and tips!